# Visenze Curl Request Error

Tags: php, curl

This is the curl request which I am using for visenze:

```
    <?php
$accessKey = '*********';
$secretKey = '*********';


    $lengthad = intval($_POST['lengtha'])-1;
    $lengthap = intval($_POST['lengtha'])+1;
    // Initialize the cURL request to ViSenze
    $ch = curl_init('http://visearch.visenze.com/uploadsearch');
    //echo $ch;
    // We want to RETURN the result not output it
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Set up the basic authentication settings
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $accessKey.":".$secretKey);

    // Define the post fields
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
        'im_url' => $_POST['im_url'],
        'score'    => $_POST['score'],
        /*'score_min'    => $_POST['score_min'],*/
        'get_all_fl'    => $_POST['get_all_fl'],
        'fl' => 'im_name',
        'fl' => 'im_url',
        'fl' =>  'category',
        'fq'=> 'category:'.intval($_POST['cat']),
        'fq'=> 'lengtha:'.$lengthad.','.$lengthap
    ]);

    //echo $ch;
    //exit;
    // Do the request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Output the results
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo  $result;
    exit;


/*echo 'Nothing posted to this script.';
exit;*/
?>
```

This doesn't gives me correct results. However, when I check in the visenze dashboard, I get correct results. I guess there is something wrong with the fq parameter while forming request.

Comment: Do you really want to tell the world your access and secret keys? They're probably now broadcast across the interwebz; better change them as soon as possible

Comment: Which result are you looking for? How about form a plain post like: im_url=$_POST['im_url']&score=$_POST['score']...

Comment: lets say $_POST['cat']=11. One I pass just 1 fq parameter, i get correct result. But when i pass two fq parameters as above, then my results are only filtered by econd fq parameter, the category fq paramter seems to be overridden

Comment: Thnaks, Baker for pointing that out. Anyways, they were for my local testing and hav changes it as well